# Backbone and requireJSe error: 404 Not Found when loading a template

Tags: templates, backbone.js, view, requirejs, underscore.js

I've got the following error messages in the console:

```
http://localhost/web/js/text.js
404 Not Found
```

if a delete text! in "text!templates/collector/indexTemplate.html" form collector_index.js, I've got the following error message:

```
http://localhost/web/js/templates/collector/indexTemplate.html.js
404 Not Found
```

main.js

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        html5shiv: "libs/html5shiv",
        jquery: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min",
        jqueryui: "http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui",
        tablesorter: "libs/jquery.tablesorter.min",
        script: "script",
        underscore: "libs/underscore.min", /*"http://underscorejs.org/underscore",*/
        backbone: "libs/backbone.min", /*"http://backbonejs.org/backbone-min",*/
        utils: "utils",
//       Collector
        collectorModel: "models/collectorModel",
        collectorCollection: "collectorCollection",
        collectorRouter: "collectorRouter",
        // Views
        index: "views/collector/collector_index",
        row: "views/collector/collector_row",
    },
    shim: {
        jqueryui: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Jqueryui"
        },
        tablesorter: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "TableSorter"
        },
        script: {
            deps: ["jquery"],
            exports: "Script"
        },
        underscore: {
            exports: "_"
        },
        backbone: {
            deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
            exports: "Backbone"
        }
    }

});

require(....
```

indexTemplate.html

```
<script type="text/template" id="indexTemplate">
    <table class="tables">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Role</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
    <a class="btns" href="#collector/new">New Collector</a>
</script>
```

collector_index.js

```
define([
    "backbone",
    "underscore",
    "row",
    "text!templates/collector/indexTemplate.html"
], function (Backbone, _, CollectorRowView) {
    var CollectorIndexView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function (options) {
            this.collectors = options.collectors;
            this.collectors.bind('reset', this.addAll, this);
        },

        // populate the html to the dom
        render: function () {
            this.$el.html($('#indexTemplate').html());
            this.addAll();
            return this;
        },

        addAll: function () {
            // clear out the container each time you render index
            this.$el.find('tbody').children().remove();
            _.each(this.collectors.models, $.proxy(this, 'addOne'));
        },

        addOne: function (collector) {
            var view = new CollectorRowView({collectors: this.collectors, collector: collector});
            this.$el.find("tbody").append(view.render().el);
        }
    });
    return CollectorIndexView;
});
```

Directory structure:

```
js
   views
     main.js
     ...
   templates
     collector
         indexTemplates.html
   main.js
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure is this a typo or not but you have **indexTemplates.html** in your collector folder and **indexTemplate.html** in your `define()`.

First make sure that you the [text.js](https://github.com/requirejs/text) plugin in the same folder where your main.js is. Create a new entry in the `main.js`:

```
'templates': '../templates'
```

The template file itself can be a plain `.html` without the `.js` extension, and you should be able to reference it by:

```
var template = require("text!templates/collector/indexTemplate.html")
```

or in `define()` if your prefer that way.

Comment: I've added 'templates': '../templates' to main.js. but it not works. Request URL:http://localhost/web/js/text.js 404 not found

Comment: you need the `text!` prefix before the template path and the text plugin. Do you have both? In which directory is your text.js?

Comment: https://github.com/requirejs/text. You have to put it in the folder where your `main.js` is.

Comment: I have put text.js in same folder than main.js and i have added: baseUrl: "js/", to main.js but i have got the following error: Request URL:http://localhost/web/templates/collector/indexTemplate.html 404 not found.

Comment: looking at the directory structure you specified in your question that file is called indexTemplates.html not indexTemplate.html

Comment: The file is called indexTemplate.html. The url must be localhost/web/js/templates/collector/indexTemplate.html with js not localhost/web/templates/collector/indexTemplate.html

Comment: then remove `'templates': '../templates'` from main.js or correct it to `'templates': 'templates'`

Comment: Now it works fine but does not show anything. The error may be in collector_index.js

Comment: Solved removing <script type="text/template" id="indexTemplate">...</script> from template. Thanks @akoskm form your time.

Comment: Exactly, I forgot to notice that you don't need those tags. :)